# Train second model while using weights in the same first layers of the first model

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

Suppose we have two models, model1 and model2. Suppose that first 10 layers are the same for model1 and model2. Then you train model1 in Keras with some dataset. You save the model in "model1.h5". Then you realize that the weights of model1 are useful for starting your training model2.I would like to do something like this:

```
# make model1  and model2
# then set weights for the first 10 layers
model1.load_model("model1.h5")
model2.set_weights[:10] = model1.get_weights[:10]
model2.compile(...)
model2.fit(...)
model2.save("model2.h5")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way of doing this using the `model.load_weights(file, by_name=True)` option. What you need is to assign the same names to layers that are shared:

```
# model 1 ...
model1.add(Dense(64, name="dense1"))
model1.add(Dense(2, name="dense2"))

# model 2 ...
model2.add(Dense(64, name="dense1"))
model2.add(Dense(32, name="notshared"))

# train model 1 and save
model1.save(filename) # or model.save_weights(filename)

# Load shared layers into model 2
model2.load_weights(filename, by_name=True) # will skip non-matching layers
# So it will only load "dense1"
```

The gist is you load model 2 weights from model 1 weights file but only the matching layer names. Layers must be same shape and type.

Comment: What if we didn't used any names for layers in model1?

Comment: If they are in the same order, they will get the same names, but I wouldn't rely on that. So first layer will be `dense_1` etc by default.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @nuric's answer and in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458370/train-second-model-while-using-weights-in-the-same-first-layers-of-the-first-mod#comment91860381_52458440), If you have not set names on the layers before training and storing the model, you can also set them after loading the model:

```
# load the model
model = load_model(...)

model.layers[index_of_layer].name = 'layer_name'
```

Then you can use @nuric's solution to load the weights. Further, to find the index of layers you can use `model.summary()`. The layers are numbered from top to bottom in that list starting from zero.